# Tracking the user who modified a journey

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, journeybuilder

I am trying to track the user who modified a journey in Marketing Cloud. I made an extract of the audit activity but the information is not listed in the report.
I've read in a post that "currently this information isn't present in the Journey Builder UI and has to be retrieved using the Audit Log API".
Could you please advise me on the way to perform this report.
Thank you

Comment: was audit log enabled at time of modification?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding to the audit log API, I will list the references to achieve this:

1. [Create and Install Packages](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/install-packages.html)
2. Ensure your scope for journey is checked with `Read`
3. Get [Access Token](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-app-development.meta/mc-app-development/access-token-s2s.htm)
4. Call [Get Journey Audit Log](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/getInteractionAuditLog.html) API

Example request for Journey Audit Log API call:

```
Host: https://YOUR_SUBDOMAIN.rest.marketingcloudapis.com
GET /interaction/v1/interactions/{Your-journey-ID}/audit/modify
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

Comment: Thank you @Duc Le for your answer. It was very helful to setup the audit trail